# Why is the button in the parent view controller not getting fired?

Tags: swift, uipageviewcontroller

I created a page view controller with the parent and child view controller. The child view controller has a clear background, and the parent view controller has a white background. When I place a button in the parent view controller, and connect it to code, and click on the button, nothing gets called. There is a connection, I triple checked. Even if the connection was fault, the button text should highlight which is not happening. For visual purposes I made the child view controller black to show where the child view controller ends and where the parent view controller starts. I set up the code, so when the button is clicked it just prints "clicked" in the console.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to think, just because it is clear, doesn't mean it can be touched. Think of it much like Glass. Glass is see-through, but you can't touch the other side. Well, the child is covering up the button, although it is clear, you are unable to touch the things behind it.

Make sense?

Comment: Like I states above, I changed the clear to black and provided an image to see where the child view controller ends and the parent starts

Comment: Can you edit your post to show code for the Parent and Child View Controllers? Might be easier to debug from this end.

Comment: I don't mind reading through all of it. Just the Parent Controller and the Child Controller.